# Getting an error using constants

Tags: php, constants

I have a lot of pages, all of which `require` the file `characters.php`. This file contains constants which define many things in my website. They are defined like this, for example:

```
const $humanHEALTH = 1.1;
```

Everything works properly running it in my localhost using WAMP, but when I upload it to an online host I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST

I used `phpinfo()` on one of the pages and the PHP version is 5.2.17.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more code, I don't believe this exact row is causing the error?

Comment: What do you have before it ?

Comment: I've added a little more clarification. Before the constants I only have the PHP opening tag.

Comment: consider using a DB to store all your const if you have a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.2 it's `define('constant_name', 'value');`

Comment: This and Marc B's answer were correct. thank you, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Support for `const` outside of class definitions was not added until PHP 5.3, so your 5.2.x is too old to use this. See http://php.net/const

Answer (score 1):

A constant must not have any `$` sign at the beginning. Try `const HUMAN_HEALTH = 1.1` instead.

As Marc B mentioned, `const` outside classes is only available up from PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

To add possible causes to those already mentioned: *use of the `$` character*, *and old PHP version*; I leave this clarification from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) that was useful to detect the problem in my case:

> As opposed to defining constants using define(), **constants defined
>   using the const keyword** must be declared at the top-level scope
>   because they are defined at compile-time. This means that they **cannot
>   be declared inside functions, loops, if statements or try/ catch
>   blocks**.