# CodeIgniter 3.1.0 to 3.1.2 upgrade miserable fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an application that has CodeIgniter version 3.1.0 and I am trying to "upgrade" to 3.1.2 (latest version)

I have no custom files in the System folder. I had renamed the system folder (for security reasons) and that change is in my index.php
As soon as I switch on the old system folder, application works just fine.

The error that I get is:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in C:\\prj\\www\\nbo\\systemXXYYZZ\\core\\CodeIgniter.php on line 58
```

Line 58 of the CodeIgniter.php is:

```
LINE 37:defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* COMMENTS IN BETWEEN */         
LINE 58: const CI_VERSION = '3.1.2';
```

My php version is 5.2.4, apache version is 2.2.6

Comment: Did you check the [instructions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) for migration?

Comment: Yes, I did. I had no custom files in the system folder and I don't use session table, so nothing to alter

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778994/getting-an-error-using-constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` won't work on php version 5.2.x.

The [latest version of codeigniter is supported only on php 5.3.7+](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_310.html), so I highly advice you to upgrade your PHP version.

You could downgrade your project to codeigniter 3.0.5, which is the last version that supports php 5.2.x, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Please don't recommend manual modifications and/or downgrades.

Comment: You are right Phiter. I will accept your answer as soon as site left me to do so (I have to wait 3 min...)

Comment: @Narf fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 3.1.x recommends PHP 5.6+ and requires *at the very least* PHP 5.3.7.

Removal of PHP 5.2 support (which nobody should need today) is prominently mentioned in the [upgrade instructions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_310.html).