# laravel "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)"

Tags: laravel, syntax

i moved my laravel project from local to sharedhost
but the laravel give this error :

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)"
```

in

```
public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php
```

host php version : 7.0

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jODrI.jpg)

Comment: but the project is fine & working in my local

Comment: what is your local php version? what work locally does not always work remotely in the exact same way. Get a VPS and use vagrant to create a similar env to your VPS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an error using constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778994/getting-an-error-using-constants)

Comment: my local php version is 7.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code only works from PHP 7.1 and up.

> Note:
>
> As of PHP 7.1.0 visibility modifiers are allowed for class constants.

[Link to documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this).

Upgrade your PHP version or use an earlier version of Doctrine's DBal.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. because my local php version is 7.1.1 & project work fine

Comment: How to fix this rather upgrading PHP version?

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Downgrade either your package version (to a version that is written for 7.0) or downgrade your whole laravel